# FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP won't open the activities back

Tags: android, android-databinding

When I call FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, it goes back to the targetted screen but when I want to navigate to activity C, it goes to activity D.

A -> B -> C -> C -> D

on screen D:

```
val intent = Intent(this, B::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
startActivity(intent)
```

Result: D -> B

on screen B:

```
val intent = Intent(this,C::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Result: B -> D

As a conclusion it simply vanishes screen C